How to write a compound name as an author in a scientific paper?
My name is (Basma) (Elamir Alaa)(Ahmed). We can see that my father name is compound of two words . If I want my name and my father name to be both included as  my author name , can I get some help of how I shall write it?!

This is very hard and no guarantee that anyone will get it correct. The problem is caused by computers and has relatively easy solutions, but nobody bothers to implement them. Fifty years ago it wouldn't be a problem. Now it is. We are going backwards on this. What if you also had a two word given name and a middle name?

It isn't a solution, but you probably need an ORCID number associated with your name, especially if you use shortened forms as you do here with your username: https://orcid.org
